# netbeans more then one main function

Tags: c++, netbeans, cygwin

Currently I am working with Netbeans on Cygwin. I want to introduce a second main function, so after the build Netbeans should produce two exe files.

Is there a possibility to configure this in the IDE?

I also took a look into the make file, which includes

```
# include project implementation makefile
include nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk

# include project make variables
include nbproject/Makefile-variables.mk
```

I guess I should edit this file, or the included files to achieve what i am looking for. But obviously i would prefer to set it inside the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Since the main function is the entry point for the executable, the compiler must be fed with only one instance of it.

In order to do what you intend to do, you would have to write two separate Makefiles. One which compiles and links with main1.cpp and the other one that compiles and links main2.cpp

I think the IDE can only help you with the ability to create personalized Build configurations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NetBeans `C/C++ Project With Existing Sources`. This type of project relies on your own `Makefile`, so you are free in what you can do there. However, it's good to have predefined target names like `build` and `clean` - then it will be easier to call these targets from the NetBeans.

Your `build` target can create any number of executables you need, however it's not  a good practice. Typically you should have targets `main1` and `main2`, and your `build` should depend on both of them:

```
build: main1 main2
```

Each target `main1` and `main2` should create its own executable:

```
main1: main1.cpp
        $(CXX) $(FLAGS) -o $@ $^
main2: main2.cpp
        $(CXX) $(FLAGS) -o $@ $^
```

BTW, this setup will allow you to build just a single executable if you want:

```
make main1
```